# Built GCC 5.4 from source; executables thus built try to link incompatible libstdc++ and fail to run

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

I have followed instructions to build GCC from source. The only modifications I made for the `configure` were:

1. using a binary suffix of `-5.4` so that I can use the compiler as `g++-5.4` for instance.
2. setting `--configure-multilib` because it wouldn't run otherwise.

I'm doing this for testing some of my code by compiling it with various different compilers. On this Centos 7 system I've got the system gcc (4.8.2) as well as clang (also compiled from source) running, and now I'd like to see 5.4 working.

Based on [these instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx), inside the source code I've put these statements to make the linker happy.

`#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0`

Now that the executables compile *and* link, I'm getting this when I run them...

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by <program name>)
```

I can't quite tell here but I do know enough to see that the actual symlink `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` links to the older one (`/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19`), and the one built as part of GCC 5.4 lives somewhere else (`/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21`). This would indicate that this program I built using 5.4 is looking at the right (old) stdlib shared lib, so something else is amiss.

Comment: If I were you I'd just use Docker with a plain Ubuntu or Debian container where you will get this compiler (as well as gcc 6.*) "for free".  That said, sometimes rebuilds are a good exercise.  Just know you have options...

Comment: gcc likes to believe VERY MUCH that libstdc++ is going to get installed in the default location. I no longer remember the details, but you need to comb through the configure options to specify a non-default installation directory. It may be necessary to jury-rig the internal default spec file it uses, to make it look at the right place and supply the correct arguments to ld (both -L and -R).

Comment: So btw. if I understand it well, you want to build with the new compiler but link the executable to use the old libstdc++? Not sure if that is possible (you would need to somehow supply the path to the old libstdc++ for linking ... or tamper the libstdc++ of the new compiler version by replacing it with the old one).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes but I did make an effort to absolutely minimize the amount of "special-configuring" that I did during my build from source, and configuration defaults to installing the new compiler into `/usr/local/` which is NOT where the system's gcc is installed (`/usr/`). The idea here is that my new GCC inherently knows where `libstdc++.so.6.0.21` lives, and that it does indeed. As far as I can tell, things have been installed to the default locations and I have no intention of changing this. (good tip there with docker, too, for really being able to scale this up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new compiler is generating code which expects to be linked to the newer libstdc++, rather than the system one. The linker finds that this expectation is not met, so it throws an error.

To fix this you will have to ensure that the correct path is being used to find and link libstdc++. There are a few options:

- Use the `-rpath` linker option. This option adds a path to the directories to be used during dynamic linking. As it is a linker option, you pass it through using `-Wl,<option>` when invoking the compiler, for example:
  `g++ ... -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib64 ...`. You may also need to add the path using the `-L` option.
- Set environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime

See also: [compiler-libstdc-version-vs-system-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451234/compiler-libstdc-version-vs-system-version)

Since you are using Centos, you may also want to check out the [devtoolset](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-4/) collection, which allows a parallel installation of newer GCC toolsets.

Comment: Awesome, I'm 99% sure you hit the nail on the head here and I'm just going to hit the checkmark once I get around to testing this out.

Comment: This worked great, but it's a bit confusing now because I think what's gotta be happening is that both stdlibs are involved with that build now because by specifying the `rpath` it can find both stdlibs so no more complaining about missing newer GLIBC. So perhaps what I'm wondering about now is how to force the new gcc to not require the new stuff and use all the old stuff. But probably it's not a reasonable or useful thing to be able to do that, because at the end of the day I'd want to have the entire system built using ONE SPECIFIC toolchain and this issue will be moot.

Comment: About your edit. Do you use devtoolset? Looks neat but will it allow me to only install some subset of those tools (just gcc for example)? Actually never mind. The answer is probably yes.

Comment: @StevenLu I have not had the chance to use it yet, although I do plan to do so soon to allow C++11 features in C6 environment

Comment: This does seem likely to be one of the most straightforward ways to get GCC 5 on Centos 6 or 7. Indeed Centos 6 comes with a horribly outdated GCC but 7's 4.8.2 is modern "enough".

Answer (score 1):

*This would indicate that this program I built using 5.4 is looking at the right (old) stdlib shared lib*

... as far as I can see, that is the wrong library, isn't it? Because it the program is built with the new g++ version, it should be using the new libstdc++, i.e. the one in `/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21`.

So then you might need to prepend that path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be able to load the program.

Comment: Yeah but I was defining `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` expressly to prevent that.

Comment: Well, maybe it still linked the new libstdc++ ... try to prepend the new path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If that will work in means the linker is linking the new one.

Comment: You know this makes sense, because the only place I "communicate" to the compiler to not use the stdlib it thinks is "right" is in the #define inside my code. Which is not a compiler flag. So this makes a lot of sense. I suppose harmic already got to the bottom of it.